# Scala compile time error, missing parameter type

Tags: scala, scalafx

I am trying to get a dialogue to get numeric input using this code

```
val dialog: TextInputDialog = new TextInputDialog{
    initOwner(Main.stage)
    title = "Set Programme Counter"
    headerText = "Numeric format not supported."
    contentText = "New PC value:"

    import java.text.DecimalFormat

    val format = new DecimalFormat("#.0")
    import java.text.ParsePosition
    editor.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter( c => {
        def foo(c:TextFormatter.Change): TextFormatter.Change = {
            if (c.getControlNewText.isEmpty) return c
            val parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0)
            val o = format.parse(c.getControlNewText, parsePosition)
            if (o == null || parsePosition.getIndex < c.getControlNewText.length) null
            else c
        }

        foo(c)
    }))
}
```

but get the missing parameter type compilation error

```
[error]         editor.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter( c => {
[error]                                                    ^
```

No idea what the parameter type should be and despite much googling cant find any useful hints.

IntelliJ does not think there is anything wrong but sbt gives the error on compile.

Comment: "No idea what the parameter type should be and despite much googling cant find any useful hints." –– `TextFormatter.Change` obviously, judging from the definition of `foo` (which isn't really needed at all BTW)

Comment: Tried that, did not work.

Comment: Too bad :) Then your `foo` definition is wrong.

Comment: Its copied code, trying to understand it not getting too far. Think it might be time for poke and hope - make any change and see what happens.

Comment: or ask the author of the code you copied ...

Answer (score 1):

The [constructor being used](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#TextFormatter-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) is of a UnaryOperator type, so the `TextFormatter.Change => TextFormatter.Change` type should be compatible.

With the Scala 2.12 REPL, this will work (using the above constructor signature with `UnaryOperator`):

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter
val tf = new TextFormatter((c: TextFormatter.Change) => c)
```

The missing type error may occur if the compiler cannot infer the matching types to a constructor, which may happen if you have an incorrect import, or possibly even an older version of Scala which doesn't match with the version being used by your IDE.

Since you say that IntelliJ did not find a problem, it seems like it's more likely the latter. Please check that your project settings in your IDE match with `scalaVersion` in build.sbt.

You may also want to reduce the inference that must be done by the compiler, by explicitly defining some of the terms. For example you can try explicit definition of a `UnaryOperator`:

```scala
import java.util.function._
val uo: UnaryOperator[TextFormatter.Change] = UnaryOperator.identity[TextFormatter.Change]()
val tf = new TextFormatter(uo)
```

Comment: Thanks, @ELinda. Been a long day will give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: Another problem  TextFormatter requires type parameter, not a clue. Tried a few things just made it worse.